# Java - how do I write a file to a specified directory

Tags: java, file, directory, bufferedwriter

I want to write a file results.txt to a specific directory on my machine (Z:\results to be precise). How do I go about specifying the directory to BufferedWriter/FileWriter?

Currently, it writes the file successfully but to the directory where my source code is located. Thanks

```
    public void writefile(){

    try{
        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("results.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
           //CODE TO FETCH RESULTS AND WRITE FILE
        }

        output.close();
        System.out.println("File has been written");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not create file");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use:

```
File file = new File("Z:\\results\\results.txt");
```

You need to double the backslashes in **Windows** because the backslash character itself is an escape in Java literal strings.

For **POSIX** system such as Linux, just use the default file path without doubling the forward slash. this is because forward slash is not a escape character in Java.

```
File file = new File("/home/userName/Documents/results.txt");
```

Comment: Not recommended, program will be bound to OS. Follow the secondary constructor as explained in other answer.

Answer (score 47):

You should use the [secondary constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) for `File` to specify the directory in which it is to be symbolically created. This is important because the answers that say to create a file by prepending the directory name to original name, are not as system independent as this method.

Sample code:

```
String dirName = /* something to pull specified dir from input */;

String fileName = "test.txt";
File dir = new File (dirName);
File actualFile = new File (dir, fileName);

/* rest is the same */
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Either that or use `System.getProperty("file.separator")`

Answer (score 5):

Just put the full directory location in the File object.

```
File file = new File("z:\\results.txt");
```

Comment: Actually you need to escape the backslash:

File file = new File("z:\\results.txt");

Or just use a regular slash File file = new File("z:/results.txt");

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is using File.separator in the paths.